# Übungen zum Lesen der Kurrentschrift

Tags: history, resource, kurrent

Gibt es eine Webseite mit Übungen, um Kurrentschrift zu lesen?

Sofort alte Briefe in exzentrischer Handschrift zu lesen, ist etwas schwierig, sodass es nett wäre, sich etwas einzuüben.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Auf der Website "Geschichte Online" gibt es einige [Übungen zur Kurrentschrift](http://gonline.univie.ac.at/htdocs/site/browse.php?a=2267&arttyp=k).

Answer (score 4):

Vielleicht nützt: [www.deutsche-kurrentschrift.de/index.php?s=abc_fraktur](http://www.deutsche-kurrentschrift.de/index.php?s=abc_fraktur) 
oder http://gonline.univie.ac.at/htdocs/site/browse.php?a=2267&arttyp=k

Es gibt viele gute Hilfen. Handschriften zu entziffern bleibt dennoch oft Schwerarbeit.

Comment: Here's a [direct link](http://www.deutsche-kurrentschrift.de/index.php?s=leseuebung_fraktur) to the _leseübungen_ on the first site @p2thei suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

http://yo-lobo.eu/fraktura_a_kurent/prepis01.php?file=prepis01
http://yo-lobo.eu/fraktura_a_kurent/prepis02.php?file=prepis02
http://yo-lobo.eu/fraktura_a_kurent/prepis02.php?file=prepis03

Das sind Links zu meiner Frakturseite auf Tschechisch mit vielen Transliterationen, sehr wohl zum Üben geeignet. Des weiteren kann man dort das Alphabet, Beispiele alter Drucke und Fonts finden.

Comment: These links are no longer working